# Schema.org Product: Same product, different quantities?

Tags: schema.org, ecommerce

How do you deal with a product that the only "variation" is the quantity pack (which changes the price per unit)?

Example:

> 100 Sheets $11.40
>   300 Sheets $32.85 (Save 4%)

Answer (score 3):

You can provide multiple [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) items for the same `Product` item.

1. `Offer` allows you to use the [`eligibleQuantity`](http://schema.org/eligibleQuantity) property:

   > The interval and unit of measurement of ordering quantities for which the offer or price specification is valid. This allows e.g. specifying that a certain freight charge is valid only for a certain quantity.
2. `eligibleQuantity` takes an [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) item as value.
3. `QuantitativeValue` allows you to use the [`value`](http://schema.org/value) property.